# Hibernate: Can I return a non-mapped list of objects that contains a List?

Tags: hibernate, native-sql, resulttransformer

I currently use .addScalar and ResultTransformer to return a non-mapped list of objects that do not have any List variables.  I'd like to modify my object to contain a List.

Following an initial example provide in Hibernate documentation, I successfully accomplished something similar to:

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID as id, NM_CDE as nameCode, NM_VALUE as nameValue FROM EMP")
 .addScalar("id", Hibernate.LONG)
 .addScalar("nameCode", Hibernate.STRING)
 .addScalar("nameValue", Hibernate.STRING)
 .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Employee.class))
```

Suppose the data was:

```
  ID    NM_CDE          NM_VALUE
  1     LEGAL           John Allan Doe
  1     NICKNM          Johnny
  1     FORMATTED       Doe, John
```

Instead of 3 objects being returned, I'd like a single object returned, assuming the above hypothetical data. The hypothetical Employee.class would be updated to contain a List of Name objects.

This:

```
private Long id;
private String nameCode;
private String nameValue;
```

Would be replaced with:

```
private Long id;
private List<EmpName> empNameList;
```

But how does the native SQL and/or Hibernate statement need to get updated?  Is this even possible?